# Why do I need parenthesis to access a Solidity contract variable in python?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3py

inside a Solidity contract there is a declaration as follows:

```
contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBase, Ownable {
address payable[] public players;
...
...
```

elsewhere in the same contract,there is a an assignment as follows:

```
....
....
recentWinner = players[someIndex];
....
....

}
```

the deploy.py Python script is used to deploy the contract. the function deploying the contract is:

```
def deploy_lottery():
      Lottery.deploy(....)
....
....
```

After deployment and doing other stuff... the contract's **recentWinner** variable is accessed from python script using parenthesis as follows:

```
def end_lottery():
      print(f"{lottery.recentWinner()} is the winner!")
```

My rather basic question is, why are parenthesis used? recentWinner is not a function that was defined in the Lottery contract. If I ran the script without the paranthesis, I get the following output.

```
<ContractCall 'recentWinner()'> is the winner!
Terminating local RPC client...
```

so it seems like the paranthesis is necessary. can somebody explain what is going on please? why should I treat this variable like a function in order to retrieve its value? if you can also point me to some related posts/reading material that would be much appreciated. thank you!

Comment: I would inspect the contents of `players` in the first place. Does it contain strings, or callable objects/functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EVM does not have public variables, only public accessor functions.

Behind the scenes, the Solidity compiler generates a function called `recentWinner()` for you. [This is called accessor or getter function](https://blog.titanwolf.in/a?ID=00750-8efeff95-ae1c-44ca-85c1-56784b7650e5). Unlike in Java etc. languages there is no `get` prefix for the function.

Comment: Thank you! this answers my question ! the the lik to the article is also very helpful

Comment: Please press the check tick button on the answer if it is a correct answer. Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Thank you Mikko !

Comment: while the recentWinner() seems to work during testing, the players(4) does not work. _players(4) is how I'm trying to retrieve the 5th element of the array **players**_ .

`assert lottery.recentWinner() == lottery.players(5) `

**players** and **recentWinner** is defined as follows inside the **Lottery** contract as follows:

`address payable[] public players;`

 Is this the correct syntax for using a getter function for arrays ? Thanks !

Comment: AFAIK there is no accessor function for arrays and you need to write getPlayer(idx) yourself. But I might be wrong, Solidity has changed a lot. I suggest you refer to the documentation.

Comment: link doesn't work